# How to set up proper bindings for material table with dropdown inside cell?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I currently have an angular material table that returns values from an api endpoint that I have. Currently, it returns the proper values except for the cells where I have a selection dropdown.

Here's a snippet of what I have for material table selection dropdown:

```
 <div class="matTable-container">
         <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Active">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ 'Active' | translate}}? </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="is-active" *matCellDef="let product">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let active of activeTypes" [value]="product._isActive">{{product._isActive}}</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let even = even; let odd = odd"  [ngClass]="{'table-even': even, 'table-odd': odd}"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        </div>
```

In the example above, currently it is binding values ['Yes', 'Yes'] instead of ['Yes','No'] albeit I specified  `activeTypes = ['Yes', 'No'];` . It seems like it is showing the value that is returned from api and existing value where Yes is replacing No.

In this scenario, how can I make sure the binding is properly displayed and the values in the dropdown are correct where the values in the dropdown should be ['Yes','No'] and the bound/selected default value should be 'Yes' for this particular item?

What am I doing wrong above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind to `mat-option` with data from `active` which is created by `*ngFor="let active of activeTypes"`.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let active of activeTypes" [value]="active">{{active}}</mat-option>
```

And bind the real data to `mat-select` via `[(ngModel)]`

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="product._isActive">
  ...
</mat-select>
```

---

For reactive form, you shall assign real value to formControls when you create them and assign those formControls to `mat-select` by binding names via `formControlName`.

Below is an example which I created a `formArray` based on datasource and bound index of form array(same as row index) to `mat-select` via `formControlName`.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" formArrayName="test">
    ...
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
        <mat-select [formControlName]="i">
          <mat-option [value]="active" *ngFor="let active of activeList">
            {{ active }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    ...
  </mat-table>
</form>

this.form = this.fb.group({
  test: new FormArray(this.dataSource.map(item => new FormControl(item.active)))
});
```

Refer working **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk?file=app/table-basic-example.html)** and **[reactive form demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk-rp5jbf?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**.

Comment: I was able to get it working with ngModel and this: [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" because I'm using Reactive Forms. Which leads me to my next question, without the 'hack' I mentioned... what else can I use instead of ngModel if I'm using a reactive form element and using ngModel is discouraged?

Comment: @Euridice01 I don't know use case of mat-table on reactive form. Let me do some search first. But If you can create the formControl, just bind the value to controls when you create them.

Comment: @Euridice01 See my updated part and a newly added demo for your problem.

Comment: @Pengyy I have two form controls that I need to add to the group and when  I add i get cannot find control with id myformarraryname-> mycolumn.. can you please give me example to add two contros to the form array please.. In your example reactive form demo can you add one more control with dropdown and bind to the grid ?

Comment: @VijenderReddyChintalapudi I think I got your problem :-)  In the demo, I used `rowIndex` to bind with formControlName, this cannot be used with more than two dropdowns per row.  Let me have a try. It may take some time.

Comment: Sure thanks @Pengyy I have two textbox controls on the grid, that I need to bind to the grid rows, so I am kind trying to figure how to add two form controls to the group and to the grid..

Comment: @VijenderReddyChintalapudi I have updated the reactiveform demo. See whether it give you some hints. :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton @Pengyy