# Angular 7 and Angular Material table with data source error when generating drop list form control for each row

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7, angular-material-6, formarray

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992158/how-to-set-up-proper-bindings-for-material-table-with-dropdown-inside-cell) on stack, I need to bind a drop down list, for each row generated from angular material table `dataSource`. The drop down list should select automatically the correspondent value, as other values.

This is table:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>


      <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="ind_id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ind. ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.iid}} </td>
      </ng-container> -->


      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [matTooltip]="element.iid" matTooltipPosition="left"> <b>{{element.far}} {{element.lar}}</b> </td>
        
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="head_hh">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Head Of HH </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hhead}} </td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="fr">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Family Rel. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index;" [formGroupName]="index">
            <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Family Relation</mat-label>
                <mat-select id="family_relation" formControlName="fr" placeholder="Family Relation">                 
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray; let i = index" [value]="frid">
                    {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
              {{element.fr}}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ms">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Marital Sts. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ms}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sts}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Age </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the typescript code, where I generate a FormArray based on this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riepzk-rp5jbf?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html) from the question attached above:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private auth: AuthApiService) {
      this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
        'fr': this.createArray()
      })
}
```

Now for each `formControl` of the array, I need to bind the data to drop list:

```
createArray(): FormArray{
    return new FormArray(this.dataSource.data.map(item=> new FormGroup({
      fr: new FormControl(item.frid)
    })));
}
```

Where `frid` is the `value` of each selected option of drop list, and `fr` is the name displayed for user.

I am having the following error:

> [ts] Property 'frid' does not exist on type '{}'. [2339]

Here a snippet of the returned array:

> 0: {0: "xyzzz", 1: "xyz", 2: 57073, 3: 2, 4: "Parent", 5:
>
> "Married", 6: "Active", 7: "no",…}
>
> 0: "xyz"
>
> 1: "zyz"
>
> 2: 57073
>
> 3: 2
>
> 4: "Parent"
>
> 5: "Married"
>
> 6: "Active"
>
> 7: "no"
>
> 8: 61
>
> age: 61
>
> far: "xyz"
>
> fr: "Parent"
>
> frid: 2
>
> hhead: "no"
>
> iid: 57073
>
> lar: "xyz"
>
> ms: "Married"
>
> sts: "Active"

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-arxoij).

How to generate form control in each row of data source in angular material 6 table ?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `Type` to `MatTableDataSource`.

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(); //<-- any which accept all kind of classes.
```

OR : recommended one

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Type>(); //<--- Type will be class or interface
```

Comment: New error after eiting to your 1st recommendation: `HhHeadComponent.html:40 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute`

Comment: The line 40 has: `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">`

Comment: Remove `[formGroupName]="index"` from the line

Comment: Still the same. you can access my code using teamviewer if you would like too.

Comment: Better would be if you can create stackblitz demo.

Comment: It exists. But i don't know why it is not importing my appMaterialModule https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-arxoij

Comment: It is working now, please check it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-arxoij

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply

```
createArray(): FormArray{
    return new FormArray(this.dataSource.data.map(item=> new FormGroup({
      fr: new FormControl(item['frid'])
    })));
}
```

Comment: I have 9 rows returned and got 9 error messages saying `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'` and the same error for `'1'` until `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '8'`

Comment: Check my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-arxoij

Answer (score 0):

Build angular form control very easily, just use annotation declare in data class, use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngform-helper-eli